# nginx enforce https works for www.example.com but not for example.com

Tags: redirect, nginx, playframework-2.1

i've implemented https enforcing through nginx in ubuntu server 12.04 lts. nginx version: nginx/1.1.19. I've added a conf file in the path /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf and include it from nginx.conf. it looks like:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

the rest of the config is just default:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
   # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

when accessing through www.example.com it correctly redirects me to the https version of the web.

Instead, when accessing through **example.com** it just goes through **http** version when should be redirected to https://www.example.com.

Is there something wrong in the configuration? Application servers is listening in **9000** and **9443** ports (http and https respectively) and are being forwarded by iptables through these rules:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9443
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your full nginx config.

Comment: there, they are default settings

Comment: Does it work if you use `site.com` to get there? That's what you have in your `server_name` line `server_name site.com www.mysite.com;`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo:
when accessing through www.mysite.com it correctly redirects me to the https version of the web.

Instead, when accessing through mysite.com it just goes through http version when should be redirected to https://www.mysite.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that nginx was being bypassed by iptables with the rule:

```
 -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
```

which I used previous to nginx installation. Actually nginx is a server listening in some port while iptables works at kernel level.

When removing this rule then all traffic on :80 went through nginx no matter if it was www.mysite.com , mysite.com with or without http prefix or any combination as I intended to.